# jq: how to change structure of JSON avoiding cartesian product?

Tags: json, jq, cartesian-product

I have thin JSON input:

```json
[
  {
    "x": [
      "2020-02-24T00:00:00",
      "2020-02-25T00:00:00",
      "2020-02-26T00:00:00"
    ],
    "y": [
      3,
      2,
      6
    ]
  }
]
```

And I would like to obtain:

```
[
  {
    "a": "2020-02-24T00:00:00",
    "b": 3
  },
  {
    "a": "2020-02-25T00:00:00",
    "b": 2
  },
  {
    "a": "2020-02-26T00:00:00",
    "b": 6
  }
]
```

If I apply [`.[]|{a:.x[],b:.y[]}`](https://jqplay.org/s/kijmcduRMw) I obtain the cartesian product (9 items).

How to change the structure of this JSON avoiding cartesian product?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Introducing a single "$-variable" keeps things brief and straightforward:

```
map(range(0; .x|length) as $i
    | {a: .x[$i], b: .y[$i]})
```

but a $-variable free solution only requires one more line:

```
map([.x, .y]
    | transpose[]
    | {a: .[0], b: .[1]})
```

Comment: Did you know that "bombastic" is insulting? :-(

Comment: nooo, I'm very sorry :( I thought it was a synonym for explosive. I'm very sorry and thank you very much